# VDI usage inconsistent between host and guest

Tags: virtualbox

`vbox 5.0.24`, `ubuntu 16.04` on host & guest (`myguest`) with dynamically allocated VDI.

Why was the VDI usage vastly inconsistent between host and guest, when I checked it below?

```
$ du -h myguest.vdi # from the host
5G

$ df -h --total # from the guest
...       used
...
total ... 2G
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Solution**

- boot guest to `recovery mode [Esc, Enter]`
- choose `drop to root shell [Down, Enter]`
- go to `Maintenance [Enter]`
- # mount -o remount,ro /dev/sda[id] /
- # zerofree /dev/sda[id]
- # shutdown -P now
- shrink the guest VDI from the host via,
- $ VBoxManage modifyhd [guest].vdi --compact

Reference:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11100/how-to-make-ext4-filesystem-sparse
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-908128.html